# Consequences of disabling fwupd

Tags: 18.04, dell, bios

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dell XPS 15 9550. Ubuntu Software Updater updated the system BIOS to 01.13.1, and I immediately experienced a large slow-down in all software with a graphical interface (web browsers became almost unusable). I experimented with lots of different graphics drivers which made no difference, and so eventually I downgraded the BIOS back to 01.10.0, which immediately fixed the problem.

I'm happy just existing on 01.10.0. Unfortunately, Ubuntu keeps trying to get me to upgrade the BIOS again. As I understand it, I could get Ubuntu to stop this by disabling `fwupd`, e.g. `sudo apt-get remove fwupd`. However, will this have any other unintended consequences?

Comment: Or, you **could** contact Dell and tell them that you think there's a problem with the new BIOS...

Comment: @heynnema I'd say Dell already knows. I specifically chose 01.10.0 for the downgrade after reading [this Dell forum here](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Dell-XPS-15-9550-is-absolute-unusable-after-BIOS-update/td-p/7376573)

Comment: I wouldn't let a forum post from Sept 2019 stop me from contacting Dell directly. BIOS 01.13.1 is newer than that forum post, and they've still apparently got it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than removing `fwupd`, just stop/disable the service... to be start/enable at a future date...

`systemctl status fwupd`

`sudo systemctl stop fwupd`

`sudo systemctl disable fwupd`

Comment: I got this error on ubuntu 23.10 box : `❯ sudo systemctl disable fwupd
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled or disabled using systemctl...`

Comment: @taiyodayo Do the first two commands work for you? Why are you trying to disable fwupd?

Comment: @taiyodayo @heynnema The same happens to me using Kubuntu 23.10. `systemctl status fwupd` and `sudo systemctl stop fwupd` work.

Comment: @Ganton You also need to use the `disable` command, or it'll restart itself during next boot.

Comment: @heynnema The `disable` command shows the error message that @taiyodayo reported. The same that happened to @taiyodayo, happens to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing `fwupd`, you can stop and disable the related services:

`systemctl status fwupd fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh.timer`

`sudo systemctl stop fwupd fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh.timer`

`sudo systemctl disable fwupd fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh.timer`

That allows you to enable and start those services when you need them. This way, you can execute `fwupdmgr` when you want.

For more extreme measures, to avoid that other software enables those services: `sudo systemctl mask fwupd fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh.timer` can be executed.

---

Note:
This method avoids the error messages that @taiyodayo wrote about.
Credits: [@heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227651/286232).