# Ubuntu Studio update will remove fwupd-signed; is this ok?

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, ubuntu-studio, fwupd

Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

System updater just said: "The following packages will be removed: fwupd-signed (1.44+1.2-3) in order to install (a whole ton of packages)."

I'll decline this for the moment until I have some confirmation that this is recommended. [Another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227508/consequences-of-disabling-fwupd) suggested disabling the service rather than uninstalling the package, but that was Ubuntu 18.xx.

So I'll decline this for the moment until I have some confirmation that this is recommended... a bit nervous about deleting something that might be needed later.

EDIT: Per recommendation below:

```
$ apt upgrade -s
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done

(deleted autoremove notice)

The following security updates require Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libimage-magick-perl imagemagick libjs-jquery-ui libopenexr25
  libmagick++-6.q16-8 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libimage-magick-q16-perl
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-60 linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-60-lowlatency
  linux-image-5.15.0-60-lowlatency linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-60 linux-modules-5.15.0-60-lowlatency
The following packages have been kept back:
  shim-signed ubuntu-advantage-tools update-notifier-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs fonts-noto-color-emoji gnome-session-canberra google-chrome-stable
  krb5-locales libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcanberra0 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libk5crypto3 libk5crypto3:i386 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0
  libkrb5support0:i386 libmysqlclient21 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g
  libsmbclient libwbclient0 linux-firmware linux-headers-generic linux-headers-lowlatency
  linux-image-lowlatency linux-libc-dev linux-lowlatency python3-pip python3-samba python3-update-manager
  python3-wheel samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs smbclient update-manager-core
42 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
27 standard LTS security updates
Inst libpam0g [1.4.0-11ubuntu2] (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libpam0g (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Inst libpam-modules-bin [1.4.0-11ubuntu2] (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) [libpam-modules:amd64 on libpam-modules-bin:amd64] [libpam-modules:amd64 ]
Conf libpam-modules-bin (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) [libpam-modules:amd64 ]
Inst libpam-modules [1.4.0-11ubuntu2] (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libpam-modules (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Inst google-chrome-stable [109.0.5414.74-1] (109.0.5414.119-1 Google:1.0/stable [amd64])
Inst libk5crypto3:i386 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386]) [libk5crypto3:amd64 on libk5crypto3:i386] [libk5crypto3:i386 on libk5crypto3:amd64] [libk5crypto3:amd64 ]
Inst libk5crypto3 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libk5crypto3 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Inst libkrb5support0 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) [libkrb5support0:amd64 on libkrb5support0:i386] [libkrb5support0:i386 on libkrb5support0:amd64] [libkrb5support0:i386 libkrb5-3:amd64 ]
Inst libkrb5support0:i386 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386]) [libkrb5-3:amd64 libkrb5-3:i386 ]
Inst libkrb5-3 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) [libkrb5-3:amd64 on libkrb5-3:i386] [libkrb5-3:i386 on libkrb5-3:amd64] [libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 libkrb5-3:i386 ]
Inst libkrb5-3:i386 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386]) [libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 ]
Inst libgssapi-krb5-2 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) [libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 on libgssapi-krb5-2:i386] [libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 on libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64] [libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 ]
Inst libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386])
Inst python3-samba [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst samba-common-bin [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst smbclient [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst samba-common [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all]) []
Inst samba-dsdb-modules [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst libsmbclient [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst libwbclient0 [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) [samba-libs:amd64 ]
Inst samba-libs [2:4.15.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.3] (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Inst libpam-runtime [1.4.0-11ubuntu2] (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Conf libpam-runtime (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Inst bind9-dnsutils [1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2] (1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst bind9-host [1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2] (1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64]) []
Inst bind9-libs [1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2] (1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Inst python3-update-manager [1:22.04.10] (1:22.04.12 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all]) [update-manager-core:amd64 ]
Inst update-manager-core [1:22.04.10] (1:22.04.12 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Inst fonts-noto-color-emoji [2.034-1] (2.038-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Inst libcanberra-pulse [0.30-10ubuntu1] (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst libcanberra0 [0.30-10ubuntu1] (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst libcanberra-gtk3-0 [0.30-10ubuntu1] (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst gnome-session-canberra [0.30-10ubuntu1] (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst krb5-locales [1.19.2-2] (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Inst libmysqlclient21 [8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1] (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Inst linux-firmware [20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.9] (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.10 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Inst linux-headers-5.15.0-60 (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Inst linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-60 (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Inst linux-headers-5.15.0-60-lowlatency (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-headers-generic [5.15.0.59.57] (5.15.0.60.58 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-modules-5.15.0-60-lowlatency (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-5.15.0-60-lowlatency (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-lowlatency [5.15.0.59.52] (5.15.0.60.53 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-lowlatency [5.15.0.59.52] (5.15.0.60.53 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-lowlatency [5.15.0.59.52] (5.15.0.60.53 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst linux-libc-dev [5.15.0-59.65] (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Inst python3-wheel [0.37.1-2] (0.37.1-2ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Inst python3-pip [22.0.2+dfsg-1] (22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Inst libcanberra-gtk3-module [0.30-10ubuntu1] (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf google-chrome-stable (109.0.5414.119-1 Google:1.0/stable [amd64])
Conf libk5crypto3:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386])
Conf libkrb5support0 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libkrb5support0:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386])
Conf libkrb5-3 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libkrb5-3:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386])
Conf libgssapi-krb5-2 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [i386])
Conf python3-samba (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf samba-common-bin (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf smbclient (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf samba-common (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Conf samba-dsdb-modules (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libsmbclient (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf libwbclient0 (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf samba-libs (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf bind9-dnsutils (1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf bind9-host (1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf bind9-libs (1:9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf python3-update-manager (1:22.04.12 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Conf update-manager-core (1:22.04.12 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Conf fonts-noto-color-emoji (2.038-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Conf libcanberra-pulse (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf libcanberra0 (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf libcanberra-gtk3-0 (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf gnome-session-canberra (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf krb5-locales (1.19.2-2ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Conf libmysqlclient21 (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [amd64])
Conf linux-firmware (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.10 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Conf linux-headers-5.15.0-60 (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Conf linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-60 (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [all])
Conf linux-headers-5.15.0-60-lowlatency (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-generic (5.15.0.60.58 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-modules-5.15.0-60-lowlatency (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-image-5.15.0-60-lowlatency (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-lowlatency (5.15.0.60.53 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-image-lowlatency (5.15.0.60.53 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-lowlatency (5.15.0.60.53 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf linux-libc-dev (5.15.0-60.66 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
Conf python3-wheel (0.37.1-2ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Conf python3-pip (22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates, Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-security [all])
Conf libcanberra-gtk3-module (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-proposed [amd64])
```

Comment: Also seeing this. Specifically, it seems to be a conflict between fwupd-signed and shim-signed, apt update will hold shim-signed back, dist-upgrade updates shim-signed and removes fwupd-signed

Comment: Best to see some command output, please run `apt upgrade -s` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: @mook765 Good point, added

Comment: @berdir indeed: "The following packages have been kept back: shim-signed" -- so it's probably OK to go ahead, then.

Comment: Looks like you can safely run `sudo apt upgrade`, no packages will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just a temporary conflict, running `apt update` and `apt upgrade` again today, I can see that both shim-signed and fwupd-signed are being updated.

I guess the update for fwupd-signed hadn't been pushed yet.

Still some other hold back packages (gnome-initial-setup ubuntu-advantage-tools), but that seems unrelated.